# pointer to a two dimentional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

How can I let a pointer assigned with a two dimensional array?

The following code won't work.

```
float a1[2][2] = { {0,1},{2,3}};
float a2[3][2] = { {0,1},{2,3},{4,5}};
float a3[4][2] = { {0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7}};

float** b = (float**)a1;

//float** b = (float**)a2;
//float** b = (float**)a3;

cout << b[0][0] << b[0][1] <<  b[1][0] <<  b[1][1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a1` is not convertible to `float**`.  So what you're doing is illegal, and wouldn't produce the desired result.

Try this:

```
float (*b)[2] = a1;
cout << b[0][0] << b[0][1] <<  b[1][0] <<  b[1][1] << endl;
```

This will work because two dimensional array of type `float[M][2]` can convert to `float (*)[2]`. They're compatible for any value of `M`.

As a general rule, `Type[M][N]` can convert to `Type (*)[N]` for any non-negative integral value of `M` and `N`.

Answer (score 2):

If all your arrays will have final dimension 2 (as in your examples), then you can do

```
float (*b)[2] = a1; // Or a2 or a3
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this is not legit in c++. You need to have an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the dimensions of b are not known to the compiler. The information gets lost when you cast a1 to a float**. The conversion itself is still valid, but you cannot reference the array with b[][].

Comment: +1 I believe this is the reason that you can't use array indices on the float**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it explicitly:

```
float a1[2][2] = { {0,1},{2,3}};
float* fp[2] = { a1[0], a1[1] };
// Or
float (*fp)[2] = a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning b to be directly equals to a1, that's mean that the pointer b is pointing to the same memory location that pointer a1 is pointing at, they carry the same memory reference now, and you should be able to walk through the array.